# Updating textview from OnProgressUpdate doesn't work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to update a `TextView` from `OnProgressUpdate()` and this is working good in my phone but, when I am using my tablet, this doesn't work. I have debugged and the code is executed but the `TextView` is not updated.

LogCat shows nothing and the price displaying in console is correct but it is not updated in the `TextView`.

This is the code:

```
public class async extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Boolean>{

    Double price;       
    DecimalFormat df;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {   
            df=new DecimalFormat("#.#");    
            txtEuros= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idEUROSVALUE);
            txtEuros.setText(Double.toString(myLote.getPrecio()));      
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... v) {
        Boolean returned=true;
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            while(WS.askSubasta())
            {                                                           
                price=myLote.getPrecio()-0.1;                   
                myLote.setPrecio(price);                                    
                publishProgress(price);
                if(comprar)
                {
                    sold=WS.Comprar(5,myLote);
                    break;
                }                                               
            }   
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            returned=false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return returned;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... p)
    {               
        try
        {
            String a=df.format(p[0]);
            txtEuros.setText(a);
            System.out.println(a);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have the layouts designed for tablets and phones?

Comment: If it is not updating, as per your code it should get some exceptions. Could you paste the log.

Comment: Make sure the id of textview is `idEUROSVALUE` in layout for tablet.

Comment: Make sure that you have the layouts for tablets well designed, as Raghunandan said.

Comment: I have done no difference between tablet and phone. Can be that the problem? Do you have some links that can help me to create an unique interface valid for all kinds of screens?